# Change active menu link color in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hyperlink, menu

I have this menu (Wordpress/Woocommerce):

[image]

I need to know how to change the link of the active page. For example, the Merchandising page.

This is the CSS code for this:

```
.nav-pills >li > a {
background color: transparent;
color: #fff !important;
}
```

I tried this:

```
.nav-pills > li.current-menu-item a {
background color: transparent;
color: #000 !important;
}


.nav-pills > li.current-menu-item>a {
background color: transparent;
color: #000 !important;
}
```

...With a lot of variations but nothing. I tried with `.nav-pills > li.current-menu-item a:active` but that change the color only when the link is clicked, not when is the actual page.
Any idea how to achieve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you give a live link?

Answer (score 0):

Normally WordPress puts you in a class called active to determine that the menu item is the one that is **current_page_item**, it should work:

```
.nav-pills > .current_menu_item > a {
   background color: transparent;
   color: #000 !important;
}
```

If you have the link on the page I could help you more